# How do I enter new AWS CodeCommit credentials for repository?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I just ran into this issue and do not see an answer posted for this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already entered credentials and deleted that user you will not be able to push to your CodeCommit repository. To enter new credentials run the following command:
`git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true`

Then try pushing again. You will be prompted to enter new credentials.